# Using transactional in spring boot with hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I am getting the error while using hibernate in spring boot application  `No qualifying bean of type TransactionManager' available`  
I am using the following config class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ct.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(St.class);

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}  
@RestController
public class RestAPIController {
 @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 @PutMapping("/addS")
    @Transactional
    public void addSt(@RequestParam("cc") String cc,@RequestParam("st") String st) {
        CC cc1= new CC();
        CC.setCode(cc);
        State state = new State(cc,st);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(state);
    }
}
}
```

The main reason I added the @Transactional in the addSt method is due to error:    `The transaction was still an active` when an exception occurred during Database.
So I turned to use spring boot for managing transactions. I am not sure what to do here.

--------------------UPDATED CODE--------------------

```
@Repository
public interface StateRepository extends CrudRepository<State, String> {}


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class StateService {

    @Autowired
    private StateRepository stateRepository;

    public void save(State state) {
        stateRepository.save(state);
    }

    public List<State> findAll() {
        List<State> states = new ArrayList<>();
        stateRepository.findAll().forEach(states::add);
        return states;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using JPA and let Spring Boot configure it? Also that code belongs in a service not in your controller, imho transactional controllers are a bad design choice.

Answer (score 1):

For starters use proper layers and write a service and use JPA instead of plain Hibernate. If you want a `Session` you can always use `EntityManager.unwrap` to obtain the underlying `Session`.

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public StateService {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public void save(State state) {
    em.persist(state);
  }
```

Use this service in your controller instead of the `SessionFactory`.

```java
@RestController
public class RestAPIController {

    private final StateService stateService;

    RestAPIController(StateService stateService) {
      this.stateService=stateService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/addS")
    public void addSt(@RequestParam("cc") String cc, @RequestParam("st") String st) {
        CC cc1= new CC();
        CC.setCode(cc);
        State state = new State(cc,st);
        stateService.save(state);
    }
}
```

Now ditch your `Config` class and restart the application.

**NOTE**

When using Spring Data JPA it is even easier, define a repository extending `CrudRepository` and inject that into the service instead of an `EntityManager`. (I'm assuming that `Long` is the type of primary key you defined).

```java
public interface StateRepository extends CrudRepository<State, Long> {}
```

```java
@Service
@Transactional
public StateService {

  private final StateRepository states;

  public StateService(StateRepository states) {
    this.states=states;
  }

  public void save(State state) {
    states.save(state);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Denium That was really interesting. But for some reason, `@PersisenceContext` annotation is showing up in red color, even though `hibernate-core` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependencies are there. Also, what do you suggest for querying the table like `select * from state`  Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need `hibernate-core` as that is included in `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. The annotation has a type, I fixed the answer, and given the fact you use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` added a `StateRepository` which makes things even easier, to answer your question in the comment you can just do `repository.findAll`.

Comment: Thanks. @PersistenceContext is working. There was some issue with Intellij. But I am getting the error: `A component required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.` `Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
`

Comment: During runtime or an IntelliJ inspection? If the latter ignore it.

Comment: @Deinum Separately, what is your opinion about my original code, which was tiny compared to the expanded one, with more classes. What do you see are the pros and cons of both approaches.

Comment: @Deinum During run time. I am getting that error

Comment: Did you put the datasource configuration in your `application.properties`? And is your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a top-level package covering the other packages?

Comment: I am using  `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. In application.properties there is just logging level defined. All the classes are in the same package and the main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
`

Comment: Remove the exclude, ditch the `hibernate.cfg.xml` and move those properties to `spring.datasource.url` etc. properties.

Comment: _use JPA instead of plain Hibernate_ - questionable advice ;) Also, `@PersistenceContext` shouldn't leak into the service layer. Regardless of whether we use Spring Data or write repositories manually.

Comment: It isn't questionable advice, you still use Hibernate underneath and can access it. With the current state of JPA you generally don't need to use native hibernate.

Comment: I am still getting the error `Field stateRepository in StateService required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.` I removed the .XML file and using application.properties
`@M.Deinum I have updated the latest code in the OP

Comment: Are all your classes detectable by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class? It doesn't seem so, and do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency as you mentioned earlier?

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringServerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringServerMain.class, args);
    }
}`
This is the main class and its inside a package called `hello`. All other classes are also inside it. the data-jpa dependency is also there

Comment: @Deinum https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fmZ77c4rTpxLguPARKXAhhPa_qmDomO1?usp=sharing This has the complete code. May be that could help where I am making the mistake

Comment: I used the maven spring-boot:run plugin from Intellij Idea and it ran fine. That's weird. But when I run the Main file from the Intellij it throws that error. Intellij drives me nuts

Comment: So if I understand correctly what we are doing here is using Spring Data JPA, is that correct? Instead of using hibernate?

Comment: You still use Hibernate but it is abstracted away. You are using JPA for which Hibernate is an implementor.